# Is it possible to use [Required] attribute in model, but not in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to use [Required] attribute in model, but not in controller.

For example I want to use object in which I will set several parameters, and for the class of this object I want to set attribute [Required].

Is it possible to use logic like ModelState.IsValid or something like it.

Here is an example of code:
EmployeeModel employee = this.ToObject(employeeXml);

Employee model has property Name. This property is required. How to verify it?

Regards, Sergey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TryUpdateModel` method which update ModelState according to model validation rules:

```
public BranchWizardStep GetNextStep(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    TryUpdateModel(_someModel);

    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:
But better to use `TryValidateModel` method which validates model only.

Comment: You just saved my day! I spent 3 hours for it yesterday! Thank you, Ivan! You are my friend!!!

Comment: >EDIT: But better to use TryValidateModel method which validates model only.
Yeah... because TryUpdateModel updates Id field :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add this in your model `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`

and then above yr property add

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This is required")]
[StringLength(100)]
```

if you also want a display name then add `using System.ComponentModel;`

and add this above yr property

```
[DisplayName("Login name")]
```

Comment: if (ModelState.IsValid) u use that in yr controller mostly on a postback

Comment: Yes, I know how to make field required, I don't know how to use thse annotations not the class which are not model. I mean this object will not be passed through Action.

Comment: >if (ModelState.IsValid) u use that in yr controller mostly on a postback
I need it not in the controller